# Property of first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: If $f '(x)$: conti-function on $\left  [ a,b \right  ]$ and exist $c (c\in (a,b))$, $f'(c)=0$
then exist $u (u\in (a,b))$ such that 
$$f'(u)={f(u)-f(a)\over b-a}$$

Comment: Are you sure it should be $f(u)$ on the RHS and not $f(b)$?

Comment: This is called the Mean Value Theorem (assuming that you meant $f(b)$ on the RHS), and follows from Rolle's Theorem. Are you allowed to apply Rolle's Theorem?

Comment: Add a condition. Once again, please look at the question

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Question was modified.

The result as stated is not correct. For example, let $f(x)=e^{10x}$, let $a=0$ and $b=1$. There is no $u$ in our interval such that $10e^{10u}=\frac{e^{10u}-1}{1-0}$.

**Remark:**  What may be intended is the [Mean Value Theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) which says that there is a $u$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f'(u)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. A puzzling thing, however, is that the Mean Value Theorem does not *require* continuity of the derivative.

Comment: Add a condition. Once again, please look at the question